# Permissão a databases com coringa

Tags: mysql

Eu preciso conceder acesso a um determinado usuário a todos os bancos de dados que iniciam com **abc** (*abc1, abc2, abcTeste, etc...*), porém novos bancos de dados podem ser criados e não queria ter que fazer isso manualmente.

Seria algo como:

> GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON "abc%".* TO 'mane'@'%';

Há alguma forma de fazer isso?

**Obs: MySQL 8**